# Cannot Install on a Thinkserver TS-140

Tags: raid

Has anyone had a successful install of Ubuntu on a TS-140 RAID?

I got it to install on my system AFTER I deleted the RAID partition into 2 separate drives.

Called Lenovo/IBM tech support and they would only say that Ubuntu was ***not*** supported!

I'm new to any version of Linux (3 or 4 days) so someone smarter than me has to have a workaround by now.  Or do I have to do as Lenovo says and buy Windows Server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server onto my Lenovo TS140 with E3-1225 cpu.  I have 2 identical 32gb SSD drives that were partitioned as RAID1 as part of the installation process.

Comment: +1 because likely relevant answer from a user with the same hardware and installation setup.

Answer (score -1):

You can install without the hardware RAID but I have ran into the same problem trying to use hardware RAID.
I'm sure you can use software RAID but kinda defeats the purpose of using the build in system.

Let me know if you find an answer as I've been looking for about 2 weeks with no luck.

Brian

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.